# Probably a silly question regarding an isPrime function

Tags: javascript, primes

My isPrime function for some reason does not work for multiples of 3.

`console.log(isPrime(9))` returns me `true`, when the number is clearly not prime. I have been staring at the logic for a while and multiple google searches yield nothing, so I am assuming it is some really dumb oversight. I could probably copy and paste to make it work but I am attempting to build proper understanding.

```js
function isPrime(num){
  for (let i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(num); i++){
    if (num % i == 0){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}

console.log(isPrime(9));
```

Comment: `i < Math.sqrt(num)` should be `i <= Math.sqrt(num)`

Comment: The square root of 9 is 3, your condition uses a strict less-than, so this executes only one loop, where `i` is equal to `2`. Try changing to less-than-or-equal-to.

Comment: Changed it still not running as desired., I can post my entire code if that helps. Sorry if this is a simple question, I feel very dumb admittedly. Not entirely sure of the etiquette of responding and what not so I appreciate the patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `i <` needs to be replaced with `i <=`
2. I added a variable to store the `Math.sqrt` call since that's an expensive operation to do every iteration.
3. Your first iteration returns `true` or `false` immediately. You should remove the `return true` from the `for` loop completely to let it iterate.

```js
function isPrime(num){
  let max = Math.sqrt(num);
  for (let i = 2; i <= max; i++){
    if (num % i == 0){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(isPrime(1));
console.log(isPrime(2));
console.log(isPrime(3));
console.log(isPrime(4));
console.log(isPrime(5));
console.log(isPrime(7));
console.log(isPrime(8));
console.log(isPrime(9));
console.log(isPrime(10));
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, running this snippet has 4 return as true, when it is not a prime number.

Comment: forgot to change `<` to `<=`, it works now

Comment: Actually updated my answer because now I understand the `sqrt` call a bit better, I misread what the code was doing beforehand

Comment: Got it, the real issue in my code was that isPrime is nested withing a sumPrime function, and I had defined max outside of isPrime. Thanks for your help, this took me way too long. edit: Yes I realized that resetting it in the loop was not ideal, I had set the variable outside the function for this reason in fact, just was dumb and didnt realize that sumPrime had access to max and isPrime did not.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of `Math.sqrt` you should write `num`.

Comment: Should be  `<= num/2` since iterating after half is pointless

Comment: In fact mathematically, iterating past the square root is pointless.

Comment: @CRice true forgot about that